# DataLabels formatter in Highchart for the first category

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have rather specific stacked bar from array and need to have two different colors/text-align dataLabels in my bar. I have names of series ['1','2','3',etc], and use it in following condition:

```js
formatter: function() {
    if (parseInt(this.series.name) % 2 == 0) {
        this.series.options.dataLabels.color =   'white';
        if (this.y != 0) {
            return this.y;
        } else {
            return null;
        }  
    } else {
        this.series.options.dataLabels.color = 'black';
        this.series.options.dataLabels.align='right';
        if (this.y != 0) {
            return this.total;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also it changes values of DataLabels.
It works good for categories '2' and '3', but not accepted to the category '1' (changing values, but not changing colors/text-align). 
Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xshx6uuL/6/
Why does it happen?
There is a possible workaround - creating an empty first bar and making it invisible,in that case formatter works fine for other bars, but this is not good idea.

Comment: Please take time to properly indent your code before asking questions about it. It makes the code so much easier to read.

Comment: I didn't understand why I can't access first bar properties, but I've solved problem with color using:

return'<span style="fill: white">' + this.y + '</span>';
But right-align for the bars with odd names is still actual

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the `align` property to `'right'` and the `color` property to `'black'` **only** when `this.series.name % 2` is equal to `0`. Your first category's name is "1", and `1 % 2` is equal to `1`, *not* 0.

Comment: No, I need align:'left' and color:'white' for cases when this.series.name % 2==0 (these are 'colored' left bars)and align:'right' and color:'black' for all other cases (these are 'grey' right bars), that's right. The problem is that doesn't affect at all to the first, upper bar